# How to find that this be always real number

Tags: symbolic, conditional

I don't know how to find out this is be real number for l[y]?

```
l[y_] := ArcTanh[Sqrt[ a + s^2 + k/(3 y^2)]/ Sqrt[a + s^2]];
l[2] /. {a -> 0.7, s -> .2, k -> 0.01}
```

Comment: `FunctionDomain[l[y], y]` will identify constraints on parameters.

Comment: I want to see for which values a,k and s always l[y] is real

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

l[y_] := ArcTanh[Sqrt[a + s^2 + k/(3 y^2)]/Sqrt[a + s^2]];

fd = FunctionDomain[l[y], y]

(* 3 a + 3 s^2 + k/y^2 >= 0 && -3 < (
  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(k + 3 a y^2 + 3 s^2 y^2)/y^2])/Sqrt[a + s^2] < 3 && y != 0 *)
```

You have four dimensions, i.e., `{a, k, s, y}`. To visualize, fix one

```
Partition[
   Table[
    RegionPlot3D[fd, {k, -5, 0.5}, {s, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {k, s, y}),
     PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a = ``", a], 14]],
    {a, -2, 3}],
   2] // Grid // Quiet
```

[image]

Then k must be less than `0`. To eliminate gap in `s` dimension, also require `a > 0`

```
SeedRandom[1234];

k = RandomReal[{-10, -0.001}]; a = RandomReal[{0.001, 10}];
Plot3D[l[y], {y, -10, 10}, {s, -5, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Exclusions -> {y == 0},
 PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a = ``; k = ``", a, k], 14],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {y, s, HoldForm@l[y]})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to show allowed y-values in dependence of a,k,s. Reduce also can yield the allowed parameter-range.

```
l[y_] = ArcTanh[Sqrt[a + s^2 + k/(3 y^2)]/Sqrt[a + s^2]];

red[a_, k_, s_, y_] = 
 Reduce[Element[{l[y]}, Reals], y, Reals] // Simplify

(*   k < 0 && (Sqrt[-a] + s < 0 || a > 0 || 
   s > Sqrt[-a]) && (y >= Sqrt[-(k/(3 a + 3 s^2))] || 
   Sqrt[-(k/(3 a + 3 s^2))] + y <= 0)   *)

StandardForm[
 red[a, k, s, y] //. 
  Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
       Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[red[a, k, s, y], {s, -5, 5}, {a, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], Mesh -> False, 
   AxesLabel -> {a, s, y}, ViewPoint -> {2, -10, 1}] // 
  Quiet, {{k, -1}, 0, -10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Allowed y in the z-direction. Result given by @BobHanlon yields the same.

```
 fdBH[a_, k_, s_, y_] = 
  3 a + 3 s^2 + k/y^2 >= 
     0 && -3 < (Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(k + 3 a y^2 + 3 s^2 y^2)/y^2])/
      Sqrt[a + s^2] < 3 && y != 0 // Simplify;
```